# VSCode vim search not working with forward slash

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the VSCode VIM keybindings plugin. - https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim

When I enter command mode, I can't seem to search, e.g. - `:/foo`

Also, when I highlight in visual mode, and enter command mode, there is not a selection present, e.g. - `:'<,'>`

Does anyone know if there is a config I need to enable for the plugin for these behaviors?

I see options that would suggest that at least search *should* be able to work. And the lexer for command mode definitely seems to suggest so, at least in the case of search via `:/` (see [this line](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/00bb9af44e0679706630f9d7ce5a43a552a67e15/src/cmd_line/lexer.ts#L49) from the plugin repo).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Aha. It seems the colon `:` does not need to precede search by slash (entering command mode).

In other words typing `/foo` directly from normal mode starts a search.